# Java Homework - Printing a triangle pattern?

Tags: java, loops

I'm struggling with an assignment. I understand that it is entirely my fault, but I've fallen behind in my classes and am struggling with this assignment.

My goal is to print the following pattern:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

Using (nested) for loops.

Would anyone be able to give me hints on how I might go about this? I've managed to print a square of asterisks, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a triangle.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Post the code that prints squares - we'll tell you how to make triangles from it, it is simpler than you think!

Comment: I would really suggest you start coding something by yourself and then if you're stuck, come back here with some code so we can give you hints and advices.

Comment: Just read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop and try to solve this problem by yourself

Answer (score 7):

First figure out how many lines you need to print out. That's your first `for` loop. Then on each line, how many asterisks do you need to print out (suppose you are on line `i`, how many asterisks are on line `i`)? Answer those questions first and the program should come easily.

Comment: Perfect answer: exactly the questions that the questioner needs to learn to ask for themselves (and to find the answer to).

Answer (score 1):

Review the following. It doesn't do exactly what you need to do but it will help get you started.

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 7; x++) {
        for (int y = x; y <= 7; y++) {
            System.out.print("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            if (y == 7) {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you basically have to print out as many asterisks as the line number, right?

I'm not allowed to give you code, as this is a homework assignment, but I can give you pseudocode.

```
start with variable i at 1, loop while i is less than or equal to 10, increment i
    // The line of code that you just wrote will execute once per line.
    // Now you can print out your asterisks.
    // Make another loop and execute it once per asterisk. That's i times, right?
    start with variable j at 1, loop while j is less than or equal to i, increment j
        print out an asterisk
    end loop
 end loop
```

Comment: This answer really helped me out a lot. Thanks so much! And everyone else of course, but this is the answer that helped me personally the most. I got working code!

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 loops for these type of problems . 1st loop is used for iteration and the second one for printing the stars. Here 1st u need to get the input from the user and store it in a variable suppose 'n' and the 1st loop should iterate till n .

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
 { System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[java8](/questions/tagged/java8) solution:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, MAX)
            .forEach(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, i)
                    .mapToObj(j -> j == i ? "*\n" : "*")
                    .forEach(System.out::print)
            );
```

Answer (score -1):

here is an outline.

```
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
   String toPrint = "";
   for (j = 1; j <= i; j++ {
      // create string of asterisks here
   }
   // print a line here
}
```

since this is homework, you should do the rest yourself

Comment: I didn't downvote - but I'm going to guess it is for creating unnecessary strings instead of printing character by character :)

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1:

```
for(int i=1; i< 10; ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j<i; ++j) {
     System.out.print("*");
   }
   System.out.println("");
}
```

Soulution 2:

```
String s = "*";

for (int i = 1; i< 10; i++) {
   System.out.println(s);
   s = s + "*";
}
```

Your choice.

Comment: Sorry for the syntax errors - spilt coffee over keyboard and shift key is sticky!

Comment: Initializing `i` at 1, and using `i < 10` will make it loop 9 times.

Comment: I did not count the number of * and it was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Okay, then. Don't worry about it. +1 for the inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String var = "";
        String exp_Str = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (i > j)
                {


                    var = var + j;
                    //Console.WriteLine(j+"");
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(var);
            var = "";

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've fixed formatting for you. Would you add some explanation to your answer?

Answer (score -2):

use a for loop

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
      System.out.print("*");
   System.out.println();
}
```

hope that helps!